# Word/phrase used to describe the search for something specific

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I trying to find a word or phrase to describe the process of looking for something specific.

So for example, if I am exploring the world in search of stamps, I am on a ......... for stamps.

Does such a word even exist??

Thanks

Comment: You're on a ***quest*** (for whatever you seek).

Answer (score 1):

You are on a "hunt" for stamps.